# jQuery pager plugin

Tags: php, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors, pagination, paging

I am looking for a jQuery pager plugin based on calculating the no. of div in specific class,
such as Spry paged view data set:
http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/spry/articles/pager/index.html

Specifically:

```
<div id=list>
    <?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
    <div id="id-<?php echo $row["idno"]; ?>" class="game">
```

This plugin must have an option which specifies the "class=game" count of all pages

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try the [jQuery Pagination](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/pagination) plugin. Here's the [demo](http://d-scribe.de/webtools/jquery-pagination/demo/demo_options.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Good plugin although for quick work, but if you want more reliable and optimize solution you have to write your own pager, like get all the repeated tags and control them from jquery, show 10 on first and when user click on next then show the next 10 and hide the prevoius 10. and so on.

for each feature you should avoid plugin, becuase when you are using plugin you have to care about that ,

i suggest you use only jquery library, no plugin becuase it will increase your bandwith and also increase your load time.